# glob.func in pprof heap profiles

Tags: go, pprof

When doing a heap profile using `go tool pprof`, I see some entries like `github.com/anacrolix/utp.glob.func1`. This doesn't correspond to any named function I can see, I assume it's a closure. What does `glob` refer to? How can I associate names like this to the appropriate function?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob` refers to global environment, `func1` means anonymous function. So it should refer to some global anonymous function. Check [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/pNcvh3MuMJ) and its panic information:

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    p = func() string {
        panic("a")

        return "asdf"
    }()
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Panic information:

```
panic: a

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x128360, 0x1040a120)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x700
main.glob.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox715198144/main.go:9 +0x80
main.init()
    /tmp/sandbox715198144/main.go:12 +0xa0
```